# How to extract HTML elements?

Tags: microsoft-excel, html

I have a few hundred of these divs, that I need sort and filter.

I would like to remove ALL HTML and be only left with the following:

**Example**

- **Name** = Keith
- **Email** = [email]keith@example.com[/email]
- **Store** = Store 1 (This only has 2 options. Store 1, Store 2)

**All of the below code is in an individual single cell, so there are about 400 cells**

```
<div userid=""286"">
    <div id=""694"">
        <h1 style=""display:none"">Keith</h1>
        <div>
            <label class=""ufo-cform-label"">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div>Keith</div>
    </div>
    <div id=""697"">
        <h1 style=""display:none"">keith@example.com</h1>
        <div>
           <label class=""ufo-cform-label""> Email Address</label>
        </div>
        <div>keith@example.com</div>
    </div>
    <div id=""698"">
        <h1 style=""display:none"">Store 1</h1>
        <div>
            <label class=""ufo-cform-label"">Please choose your closest store</label>
        </div>
        <div>Store 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this even possible in excel?
Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a lot of detail sadly, making an answer tricky.

Are the cells in the same format? Is it the HTML that changes or only the values. Are you always looking for Name, Email and Store? Are the line breaks in the same place? You also don't mention if you want to use a worksheet formula or VBa.

Based upon the example you've given, this VBa should do the basics, or at least give you enough to get going.

```
Sub DoTheThingTheyWant()

Dim myValue As String
myValue = Range("A1").Value

Dim myValueSplit() As String
myValueSplit = Split(myValue, ">")

Dim nameSplit() As String


Range("B1").Value = "Name: " & GetValue(myValueSplit, 9)
Range("B2").Value = "Email: " & GetValue(myValueSplit, 13)
Range("B3").Value = "Store: " & GetValue(myValueSplit, 29)

End Sub


Function GetValue(myValueSplit() As String, pos As Integer)

Dim result() As String

result = Split(myValueSplit(pos), "<")

GetValue = result(0)


End Function
```

Remember, always save a copy of your work first as a back up as Macro's don't undo!!

Comment: Dave, thanks so much for the reply. I'll have a go and see what I can do with your code. Much much appreciated.

Comment: @KeithDonegan, feel free to edit your original question and include the answers to the questions I asked... It may mean you get a different/better/alternative answer

Comment: Dave, could you contact me please. [keith AT chocolate-ltd DOT com] Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but I needed an answer for myself and needed to manually do it without VBA. Just used nested substitutions so easy for non-VBA users:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@Description],"<html-blob>",""),"gt;",""),"</i>",""),"<i>",""),"</html-blob>",""),"</a>",""),"amp;",""),"<br />",""),"</span>",""),"&nbsp",""),"<a href=",""),"</b>",""),"<span>",""),"<br>",""),"<b>",""),"</u>",""),"<u>","")
```

To use it, swap the "[@Description]" for your source data.

To add more, just copy the middle substitute function looking like this:

`SUBSTITUTE([@Description],"<html-blob>","")`

and paste it into the source in the formula, here "[@Description]", because I used this in a table. Change the duplicate substitute.